# How to partial update entity

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

May someone show an example with a partial update entity? All examples into git/docs/stack have only update method, which replaces all fields, even I sending null.

It looks like I need to use HttpPatch and json-patch. But it's so much extra code...

UserEntity

```asp
 public class User: AbpUser<User>
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        [StringLength(MaxNameLength)]
        public override string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        [StringLength(MaxNameLength)]
        public override string Surname { get; set; }

        public string FatherName { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public long? ManagerId { get; set; }

        public long? PositionId { get; set; }

        public override string FullName => $"{Surname} {Name} {FatherName}";
    }
```

CreateUserDto

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "surname": "Test",
  "emailAddress": "test@test.test"
}
```

UpdateUserDto

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Василий",
  "surname": "Пупкин",
  "fatherName": "Иванович",
  "birthDate": "1993-02-21",
  "emailAddress": "vasiliyp@test.test",
  "phonenumber": "+79378889911",
  "departmentId": 1,
  "positionId" : 1
}
```

Second UpdateUserDto

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Василий",
  "surname": "Пупкин",
  "fatherName": "Иванович"
}
```

After the second update I want to get a partial update, but it updates all fields include those I do not send. For example, PositionId will be null, instead of 1.

UserAppService

```asp
        public override async Task<UserDto> UpdateAsync(UpdateUserDto input)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(input.Id);

            MapToEntity(input, user);

            return await GetAsync(input);
        }
```

```asp
        protected override async void MapToEntity(UpdateUserDto input, User user)
        {
            ObjectMapper.Map(input, user);
            user.SetNormalizedNames();

            if (!user.DepartmentId.HasValue || user.DepartmentId == 0) return;

            var department = await _departmentRepository.GetAsync((long)user.DepartmentId);
            user.ManagerId = department.ManagerId;
        }
```

**Update**

Yesterday I find a way: it needs to customize automapper that to merge models.

```asp
Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
  cfg => cfg.ForAllMaps((obj, cnfg) => cnfg.ForAllMembers( 
  opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))));
```

But there are problems:

1. All value types into DTO must be nullable because the automapper will get default values.
2. Even though I have defined DateTime as nullable, the automatic conversion converts it to the default (DateTime). I have not yet found a way to fix this without a crutch.

```asp
if(input.BirthDate == null) input.BirthDate = user.BirthDate;
```

**UPDATE 2**

```asp
    [AutoMapTo(typeof(User))]
    public class UpdateUserDto : EntityDto<long>
    {
        [StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxNameLength)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxSurnameLength)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string FatherName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxEmailAddressLength)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public long? PositionId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create new Dto with specific fields and create new Update function for that.

Comment: He has already defined the new DTO and as long as the new Update method uses the base Update, the rest of the properties will be overridden by null or default values.

Comment: Yep, i defined. 
Yesterday i find a way: it need to customize automapper that it to merge models. But i have some problems: 
`Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
                    cfg => cfg.ForAllMaps(
                        (obj, cnfg) => cnfg.ForAllMembers(
                            opts => opts.Condition(
                                (src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)
                            )
                        )
                );`

Comment: no need to customize you'r mapper, you have to remove all properties/ fields from Dto the t you won't to be apply. another word create a Dto with specific fields that you want.

Comment: Is it the best practice to build a web API? I thought that web API does not matter what interfaces are needed for clients.

If clients want to update the user entity into several places - web API should give 1 Update method for all of them. For example, I have 3 places in my UI that can edit user entity - user card, departments list, operation with documents. 

Are you suggest create an Update for every place, with its own DTO models?

Comment: so you write one endpoint for all these three state, if some body access to this endpoint some how, what happen? she/he can change anything. some times we have to separate them. of course this is my opinion you can search more about this.

Comment: can change anything - yes. An endpoint may change all property that is public for it. But it's doesn't matter for backend API - we only must to validate the model. If clients (frontend, mobile app, another API) update something excess into a model - it's the client's problem and own business logic of using data.

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed out, all values in the update DTO must be declared nullable, or it will be assigned default values.

Then you also need to convert nullable type to using destination value instead.

```
// example for int, double and DateTime
CreateMap<int?, int>().ConvertUsing((src, dest) => src ?? dest);
CreateMap<double?, double>().ConvertUsing((src, dest) => src ?? dest);
CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime>().ConvertUsing((src, dest) => src ?? dest);

// ignore if null
CreateMap<UpdateDTO, UpdateEntity>()
     .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```